# Check if unix pipe closed without writing anything?

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe

Basically I have a parent process that forks a child and feeds it it's stdin through a pipe. The child process can terminate in one of two cases:

- the write end of the pipe is closed by the parent, meaning it reached the end of stdin thus receiving an **EOF**,
- or it receives a certain input through the pipe(**-1** in this case) and exits

My parent code looks roughly like this:

```
close(pi[0]); // close input end
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); // do not handle SIGPIPE
char buffer;
int ok = 1;
while(ok && read(STDIN_FILENO, &buffer, 1) > 0)  {
    int b_written = write(pi[1], &buffer, 1);
    if(b_written == -1) {
        if(errno == EPIPE) ok = 0;
        else perror("pipe write"); // some other error
    }
}
```

As you can see, I check whether the read end of a pipe is closed by checking for `errno == EPIPE`. However this means that the read loop does one extra iteration before closing. How could I possibly poll to see if the pipe is closed without necessarily writing something to it?

Comment: What is the problem with your current way of handling things? What you can do to check the child is alive could be more costly than doing one more `write()` than necessary.

Comment: Read up on `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: @jdarthenay it works but after the child dies it waits for another input in stdin before it exits

Comment: Do you have control over the child code? Can you have it use `kill()` when it terminates?

Comment: Even if you find a way, you have a race condition. Oh well, most of the time it will do the right thing.

Comment: Even if you poll, extra stdin reading may happen! Suppose you poll and the answer is ok, then you read, but since then the pipe was closed on the other end?

Answer (score 9):

This snippet will check if the other end of a writable pipe is closed using `poll(2)`.  This works on Linux -- I'm not sure about other OSes or what POSIX says.

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool is_pipe_closed(int fd) {
    struct pollfd pfd = {
        .fd = fd,
        .events = POLLOUT,
    };

    if (poll(&pfd, 1, 1) < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return pfd.revents & POLLERR;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The child could send a signal, such as `SIGUSR1` when it detects it has finished. Parent could set a flag to when it receives `SIGUSR1` signal, and check this flag before trying to read input. But I am not absolutely sure `SIGUSR1` could not be received after checking the flag ans before reading input from `stdin`). So I prefer to use a control pipe, each time child know it will be able to read one more data it write a 1 in this control pipe. The result could be something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define STOP_VALUE 100
#define SIZE_STDIN_BUFFER 1024

static char can_read_more = 1;

static int handle_child(int *p_child_input_stream, int *p_control_stream)
{
    int pipefd[2][2];
    pid_t fk;

    if (pipe(pipefd[0]) < 0) // Pipe to read input from 
    {
        perror("pipe");
        return -1;
    }

    if (pipe(pipefd[1]) < 0) // Pipe to notifiate parent input can be processed
    {
        perror("pipe");
        close(pipefd[0][0]);
        close(pipefd[0][1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if ((fk = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        close(pipefd[0][0]);
        close(pipefd[0][1]);
        close(pipefd[1][0]);
        close(pipefd[1][1]);
        return -1;
    }

    if (fk == 0)
    {
        close(pipefd[0][1]);
        close(pipefd[1][0]);
        write(pipefd[1][1], &can_read_more, sizeof(char)); // sizeof(char) == 1

        ssize_t nb_read = 0;
        char buffer;
        while (nb_read >= 0)
        {
            nb_read = read(pipefd[0][0], &buffer, sizeof(char));
            if (nb_read > 0)
            {
                printf("0x%02x\n", (unsigned int) buffer);
                if (buffer == STOP_VALUE)
                {
                    nb_read = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    write(pipefd[1][1], &can_read_more, sizeof(char));
                }
            }
        }
        close(pipefd[0][0]);
        close(pipefd[1][1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    close(pipefd[0][0]);
    close(pipefd[1][1]);

    *p_child_input_stream = pipefd[0][1];
    *p_control_stream = pipefd[1][0];

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int child_input_stream;
    int control_stream;

    if (handle_child(&child_input_stream, &control_stream) < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char stdin_buffer[SIZE_STDIN_BUFFER];
    char buffer;
    int ok = 1;
    int child_available_input = 0;

    while(ok)
    {
        while (child_available_input <= 0 && ok)
        {
            ssize_t nb_control = read(control_stream, &buffer, sizeof(char));
            if (nb_control > 0)
            {
                child_available_input += buffer;
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "End of child reading its input detected.\n");
                ok = 0;
            }
        }

        if (ok)
        {
            if (fgets(stdin_buffer, SIZE_STDIN_BUFFER, stdin) == NULL)
            {
                ok = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (stdin_buffer[strlen(stdin_buffer) - 1] == '\n')
                {
                    stdin_buffer[strlen(stdin_buffer) - 1] = '\0';
                }

                char dummy;
                int input;
                if (sscanf(stdin_buffer, "%d%c", &input, &dummy) == 1)
                {
                    buffer = (char) input;
                    write(child_input_stream, &buffer, sizeof(char));
                    child_available_input--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```